# "Run client channel backup poller" GRPC client error in Celery worker

Tags: python, celery, grpc

I am working with GRPC and Celery in Python. When running functions which call to GRPC server in a celery worker, the celery worker log shows a lot of lines:

```
E1018 16:17:46.449758455     101 backup_poller.cc:133]       Run client channel backup poller: {"created":"@1634573866.449735058","description":"pollset_work","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":321,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1634573866.449730704","description":"Bad file descriptor","errno":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":952,"os_error":"Bad file descriptor","syscall":"epoll_wait"}]}
E1018 16:17:51.449779383      34 backup_poller.cc:133]       Run client channel backup poller: {"created":"@1634573871.449756248","description":"pollset_work","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":321,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1634573871.449754215","description":"Bad file descriptor","errno":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":952,"os_error":"Bad file descriptor","syscall":"epoll_wait"}]}
E1018 16:17:56.449816371     101 backup_poller.cc:133]       Run client channel backup poller: {"created":"@1634573876.449790405","description":"pollset_work","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":321,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1634573876.449786443","description":"Bad file descriptor","errno":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":952,"os_error":"Bad file descriptor","syscall":"epoll_wait"}]}
```

While running, Celery Worker crashes many times with **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error. I cannot find out the root cause of this error.

```
E1018 16:10:18.593682050      33 backup_poller.cc:133]       Run client channel backup poller: {"created":"@1634573418.593660900","description":"pollset_work","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":321,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1634573418.593658189","description":"Bad file descriptor","errno":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":952,"os_error":"Bad file descriptor","syscall":"epoll_wait"}]}
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error recently trying to call gRPC client as the part of the celery worker task.
The common command: `celery -A app worker -l info -c 1` resulted in:

```
[2022-05-23 14:44:44,585: INFO/MainProcess] celery.worker.strategy: Task io_bound:get_landmarks_via_grpc[ebb65e3d-cef5-4b22-88d6-947a2560f4c1] received
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

According to [this GH issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13260) the problem is that celery uses **prefork pool** by default while gRPC doesn't support forking ([more details here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/fork_support.md)).

So if you choose a different pool option, e.g. 'gevent', it works.
`celery -A app worker -l info --pool=gevent -c 1` results in the succeeded task.

More about celery execution pools: https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/